# When I tried to get json structure I got this "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict"

Tags: json, python-3.x

I am calling a API with this code but I got a error when I tried to get the JSON structure I got this error:

> File "`<ipython-input-8-59af996ee581>`", line 12, in  `result = results[result_id]`
>
> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict

```
from client import RestClient

client = RestClient("jxxxxxx@xxxx.com", "xxxxxxxyyyyy")
completed_tasks_response = client.get("/v2/srp_tasks_get")
if completed_tasks_response["status"] == "error":
    print("error. Code: %d Message: %s" % (completed_tasks_response["error"]["code"], completed_tasks_response["error"]["message"]))
else:
    results = completed_tasks_response["results"]
    print(results)
    for result_id in results:
        result = results[result_id]
        srp_response = client.get("/v2/srp_tasks_get/%d" % (result["142657080"]))
        if srp_response["status"] == "error":
            print("error. Code: %d Message: %s" % (srp_response["error"]["code"], srp_response["error"]["message"]))
        else:
            print(srp_response["results"])
```

Comment: The error is self-explanational. Can you add the result from that `print(results)` (or part of it if it is longer) ?

Comment: I am new in code, this is json :[{'post_id': '1', 'post_key': 'pasaje miami', 'task_id': 142657080, 'se_id': 89, 'loc_id': 1003325, 'key_id': 28230120, 'results_count': 565000, 'result_extra': 'knowledge_graph', 'result_spell': '', 'result_se_check_url': 'google.cl/…;}] Traceback (most recent call last): File "<ipython-input-8-59af996ee581>", line 12, in <module> result = results[result_id] TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict

Answer (score 0):

You don't show us the JSON you are trying to parse (**why?**), but, as the error says, `results` is a list of dictionaries and not integers, which doesn't seem like what you expected it to be.

You should either:

Iterate over `result` dictionaries that `results` contains:

```
for result in results:
        srp_response = client.get("/v2/srp_tasks_get/%d" % (result["142657080"]))
        ...
```

Or make sure you are using the API correctly.

Comment: I am new in code, this is json  :[{'post_id': '1', 'post_key': 'pasaje miami', 'task_id': 142657080, 'se_id': 89, 'loc_id': 1003325, 'key_id': 28230120, 'results_count': 565000, 'result_extra': 'knowledge_graph', 'result_spell': '', 'result_se_check_url': 'https://google.cl/search?q=pasaje%20miami&hl=es-419&gws_rd=cr&uule=w+CAIQIFISCS-vJQRBxWKWETEJD0A81XWE'}]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-8-59af996ee581>", line 12, in <module>
    result = results[result_id]

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict

Comment: @JulioMoyanoBasso So my answer should work. Also, make sure you are using `result['task_id']`  instead of `result["142657080"]`.